# Eclipse showing error on MapFragment.getMap() line

Tags: android

Eclipse show an error on `MapFragment.getMap()` line; here is my source code:

**MapActivity :**

```
public class MapActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // replace content_menu fragment with map fragment
        FragmentTransaction fragTans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragTans.replace(R.id.content_frame, new MapFragment());
        fragTans.commit();
    }
}
```

**MapFragment**

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Map setup 
    View mapView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_layout, null);

        // Eclipse show me that getMap is not exist here 
    GoogleMap mapGoogle = ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_view)).getMap();

    // ... customize my map , add marker ....
        return mapView;
    }
}
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_tab_fragment, container, false);
SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
map = fm.getMap();
```

Comment: use supportMapFragment in xml file to run in all version

Comment: Even your help might be helpful, it's always a good idea commenting out why this works and which makes the difference with OP's code.

Comment: Indeed the original question is lacking in details about what the problem is as it is; your answer should explain why it answers the OP's question.

Comment: @NKN ok thnxs for giving me suggestion i m new over here

Comment: Sorry guys, after a lot of trouble? I found that eclipse has confused my class Named MapFragment which is already predefined !

I changed it to MapsFragment and now it's working ...